# Spoiler markup broken when used with pictures

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, spoilers, markdown

When you throw a picture into the

> otherwise working spoiler markdown.

Like this:

```
>! ![The nicest tux ever.][1]
```

Then you notice that, surprise, surprise,

> [image: The nicest tux ever.]

It doesn't work. I.e. the picture is not hidden when the spoiler box is not being hovered over.

Comment: Spoilerification uses a basic font color CSS trick with `:hover`..  I'd call this "by design", if I had to guess, since it would've been the simplest and most cross-browser way to do it.

Comment: @Izkata: How can this be "by design". There could easily be a specialisation of `.spoiler img {display:none;}` as `.spoiler:hover img {display:inline;}`.

Comment: And flickerflickerflicker as the spoiler box keeps changing size. ;)  But yeah, there's probably a way to do it that's just not popping into mind.  I know there's `opacity` CSS, but it's not cross-browser, you have to use specific attributes for specific browsers IIRC.

Comment: @Izkata: Good point. There was a CSS property that allowed you to tell the user agent not to display something but statically reserve the required space. My CSS is a bit rusty, apparently.

Comment: @bitmask `{visibility:hidden;}`

Comment: @Keen: Exactly!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the fix will be in the next production build. thanks for the visibility: suggestion.

Comment: Great. Thanks!_

Comment: In IE 8 I can no longer roll over to see the image. Is this IEs lameness or a change you've made?

Comment: Same thing for FireFox 15.0.1

Comment: @Pureferret what version of IE are you using?

Comment: @Jin I'm in IE 8, like I say above. Version 8.0.6001.18702 to be precise.

Comment: @Pureferret I just checked. It's not IE lameness this time. I messed up on the fix. I just fixed the... fix. It will be in the next prod build sometimes today. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Jin no worries, you do an awesome job round here regardless!